# Individual UI element transparency in windows phone

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8, opacity

So i was making this app in which I set a background on which there is a grid which has high opacity. I wanted buttons on the grid that had lower opacity than the grid and hence, the background is more visible through the buttons in comparison to the grid. Any idea on how i can do that?

Comment: Did you try giving the `Opacity` as 0.5 within your `Button`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Thing is that since my button is on top of the grid the grid's opacity basically gives an upper bound. So I can make the button look darker than the background, but  not the other way around. I wanted something like this- 
[link](http://cdn.marketplaceimages.windowsphone.com/v8/images/45bb8591-666b-4cfa-936a-28c64157263d?imageType=ws_screenshot_large&rotation=0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `button` control opacity less than `grid` control opacity.
You can able to set opacity of any control in between 0.1 to 1.

```
    <Grid Background="Red "
          Grid.Row="1" >
           <Button Background="Green"
                   Opacity=".2" 
                   Content="Button" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid 
              Grid.Row="1" >
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/backgroundImage.jpg">
                    </ImageBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Button 
                   Opacity=".4" 
                    Background="#504E4E"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                    Content="Button" 
                    Foreground="#FFFFFF"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="32,32,231,389" 
                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                    Height="186" 
                    Width="193"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

This will surly help you.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it and couldn't get the result that i was looking for. I wanted the grid's opacity to be higher than that of the buttons. So the background should be darker at the grid and lighter at the buttons. Something like this [link](http://cdn.marketplaceimages.windowsphone.com/v8/images/45bb8591-666b-4cfa-936a-28c64157263d?imageType=ws_screenshot_large&rotation=0)